# What's the best approach to attaching encrypted files to NFTs?

Tags: nft

For example, how would I approach attaching sensitive data to a token. In my particular case I would like to attach comic pages to a "Comic NFT", and keep the pages private so that only the NFT owner can decrypt the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about it would be by using the [Darkblock protocol](https://www.darkblock.io/)

It supports Solana, amongst other blockchains. In a nutshell, it's a protocol which allows you to "mint a darkblock" which is points to an encrypted file on arweave. Attaching the NFT to the darkblock is done by specifying the `darkblock-id` in the NFT metadata.

One NFT can have multiple darkblocks (files) attached, one darkblock can represent one file and be attached to multiple NFTs. In the comic example above, your whole comic NFT collection would only have a single Darkblock minted (*comic-pages.pdf*) or more blocks if you prefer attaching images instead (*comic-page-1.jpg, comic-page-2.jpg...*)

There are prob alternatives that I'm not aware of